# How to change size of column in ROOM android?

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am new in android and got fascinated with Room library. I tried most thing mentioned in the documentation but couldn't implement database size. For example when we make a table in SQL we can,

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);
```

here we can define my column length but i can't find same option in ROOM.

Answer (score 2):

Android database fundamentally is use SQLite include ROOM.

[SQLite Datatypes](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

```
NULL. The value is a NULL value.

INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

REAL. The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number.

TEXT. The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).

BLOB. The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.
```

Note that numeric arguments in parentheses that following the type name (ex: "VARCHAR(255)") are ignored by SQLite - SQLite does not impose any length restrictions (other than the large global SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH limit) on the length of strings, BLOBs or numeric values.

Comment: Numeric arguments within parentheses although ignored length wise are syntactically checked. If one of the parentheses is omitted an incomplete input error (trailing) or syntax error (leading) will result. Furthermore, the value within has to be numeric. That is unless the errant column type is enclosed e.g. `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS thetable (col [varchar1)]);` works but `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS theothertable (col varchar1));` fails.